# find string in matrix using 'match'

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the match formula to see if the value "A.VOGEL" is found in a matrix (A4:A8).
I have this formula:
`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("A.VOGEL";A4:A8));"A.VOGEL";"")`

when this is the range of values the formula works:

`A4: A.VOGEL
A5: OTHER BRAND 1
A6: OTHER BRAND 2
A7: OTHER BRAND 3
A8: OTHER BRAND 4`

when this is the range of values the formula does not work:

`A4: OTHER BRAND 1
A5: OTHER BRAND 2
A6: A.VOGEL
A7: OTHER BRAND 3
A8: OTHER BRAND 4
(where A.VOGEL could be in A5, A6, A7 OR A8)`

When A.VOGEL is in a4, the formula works. But when it is in A5, A6, A7 or A8, my formula does not work. The match formula then returns `#N/B`

I do not understand why the match formula cannot return the position of A.VOGEL when it is not the first in the given matrix. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: In dutch, the formula is: `=als(isfout(Vergelijken("A.VOGEL";A4:A8));"A.VOGEL";"")`

Comment: That's true. The answer worked for me. Also see my comment on that answer: I also do not see how I am getting and #N/B on my formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH("A.VOGEL";A4:A8;0)));"A.VOGEL";"")
```

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion worked. But I would like to know why my formula only worked if A.VOGEL was in the first cell of the matrix.

Comment: I think I may have a clue why my formula didn't work: I forgot the semi-colon and 0 after I entered the search matrix. The formula then used the first closed value as valid? only addding `;0` would be enough I guess. I have checked it, this works: `=ALS(ISFOUT(VERGELIJKEN(A.VOGEL;A13:A17;0));"";"A.VOGEL")`